# How to remove ManyToOne JPA object

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm trying to remove object of child class without calling parent class so there's no need in 2 requests to database. Can you help to solve this problem and explain how to fix this.

Parent class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<License> licenses;
```

Child class:

```
@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private Person user;
```

Trying to delete:

```
@Transactional
public void delete(License license) {
    licenseRepository.delete(license);
}
```

If I do CascadeType.ALL on Child (license) class, it removed parent class too. I need to remove only this license from database

Comment: It looks like `License` is actually the child class. But you have them labeled opposite. Can you clarify? On the child, you will definitely need something other than CascadeType.ALL. Perhaps just REFRESH and DETATCH. You may also want `orphanRemoval=true` in that annotation.

Answer (score 1):

So here as i can see you have a parent class *User* and a child class *License* with a OneToMany Bi-Directional mapping.

Here in the Many side means in your License entity side, as long as you don't use the *CascadeType.REMOVE*, if you delete a license object it wont delete the user object.

so you can directly delete the license entry.
It will look something like this:

licenseRepositoryObject.delete(licenseObjectToBeDeleted);

Answer (score 0):

Before deleting the child class using

```
  @Transactional
   public void delete(License license) {
   license.setUser(null);
  licenseRepository.delete(license);
    }
```

So that all relations between parent and child are removed